# Good textbooks for fluid mechanics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations

What is a good textbook for second year fluid mechanics (materials engineering/science)?  Currently, I am using Gaskell, "An Introduction to Transport Phenomena in Materials Engineering".

Thanks